# Energy produced from respiration

Tags: energy

Why is the amount of ATP Produced from anaerobic respiration is less than the amount produced from aerobic respiration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anaerobic respiration does not completely oxidize the glucose, and as a result, pyruvate is not completely broken down, yielding fewer ATP molecules, and there are leftover molecules: lactic acid in animals and ethanol in yeast. This is because anaerobic respiration does not utilize oxygen, which is required for the electron transport chain, where most of the ATP comes from in aerobic respiration. In aerobic respiration, the glucose molecule is completely oxidized, and so (through the Krebs cycle and the electron transport chain, which requires oxygen and which produces the majority of the ATP) is completely broken down into carbon dioxide and water.